# Apex charts in Angular 9

Tags: html, angular, typescript, apexcharts

I have some problem using apex charts in angular 9, essentially I'm able to see the chart (line chart) when I mock the data as in the first screenshot, but I can't get data from REST API, I mean the chart disappears.
[mocked datas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVMH4.png)

This is the method containing the chart:

```
      drawGraph(){
    this.projectService.getLineChartData(this.getID()).then((data) =>{
      
      for(let i = 0; i<data.resourceListSize; i++){
    
      this.chartOptions = {
        series: [
          {
            name: "data",
            data: [28, 29, 33, 36, 32, 32, 33]
          },
          {
            name: "Low - 2013",
            data: [12, 11, 14, 18, 17, 13, 13]
          }
        ],
        chart: {
          height: 350,
          type: "line",
          dropShadow: {
            enabled: true,
            color: "#000",
            top: 18,
            left: 7,
            blur: 10,
            opacity: 0.2
          },
          toolbar: {
            show: false
          }
        },
        colors: ["#77B6EA", "#545454"],
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true
        },
        stroke: {
          curve: "smooth"
        },
        title: {
          text: "Average High & Low Temperature",
          align: "left"
        },
        grid: {
          borderColor: "#e7e7e7",
          row: {
            colors: ["#f3f3f3", "transparent"], // takes an array which will be repeated on columns
            opacity: 0.5
          }
        },
        markers: {
          size: 1
        },
        xaxis: {
          categories: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul"],
          title: {
            text: "Month"
          }
        },
        yaxis: {
          title: {
            text: "Temperature"
          },
          min: 5,
          max: 40
        },
        legend: {
          position: "top",
          horizontalAlign: "right",
          floating: true,
          offsetY: -25,
          offsetX: -5
        }
      };
    }
  })
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you

Comment: i think you can first filter out the data you want to represent on the chart and the render the chart with data that is available from api

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1,**
*set the configuration with out data like below(minimum configuration)*

```
this.chartOptions = {
 series: [],
 chart: {
     height: 350,
     type: "line"
 },

 xaxis: {}
```

}

Step 2:
Data from api response and set to "chartoptions" variable,

```
  this.chartOptions.series=[{
         name: "data",
         data: [28, 29, 33, 36, 32, 32, 33]
     }, {
         name: "Low - 2013",
         data: [12, 11, 14, 18, 17, 13, 13]
     }
 ];
 
 this.chartOptions.xaxis=
 {
     categories: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul"]
 }
```